# React.createElement: type should not be null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, redux

Firstly, i hope this is not an duplicate - i'm using ES6, not regular `extends React.Component`.

This is my `Layout` component. I'm implementing this to `app.js` as `import Layout from './components/Layout';` and console is throwing the error:

`React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of "Layout".`

```
const Layout = (props) => {

    let { location } = props;

    return (
        <div>
            <Nav location={location} />
            <main>
            </main>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Layout;
```

What is wrong? This is React/Redux env.

Comment: you should check import

Comment: why, what is wrong with it?

Comment: If `main` is component , it should start with 
capital letter. Check in console `Nav`, it should not be undefined

Comment: This warning means during `import Layout from './components/Layout'` something went wrong and Layout variable is null :) Could you show your app.js, directory structure? Also are you using webpack or something?

Comment: I'm using webpack

Comment: I've found the issue, there is problem with `<Nav location={location} />` implementation, but why?  implementing this like that - `import Nav from 'layout/Nav';`

Comment: I think without the tree structure we can't help you (

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `export` statement is wrong as seen in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export):

> Note that it is not possible to use var, let or const with export default.

Try changing

```
export default Layout;
```

to

```
export { Layout as default };
```

Comment: sorry, this is not it, still have this issue :(

Comment: Hmm, did you add 'import React from 'react';' at the beginning of Layout?

Comment: I've found the issue, there is problem with `<Nav location={location} />` implementation, but why? implementing this like that - `import Nav from 'layout/Nav'`;

Answer (score 0):

The error says `Check the render method of "Layout".`

This is a good hint that the error is not coming from `app.js` but from within your `Layout` component. Likely it is how you are importing `Nav`. If your import statement looks like this:

`import Nav from "/path/to/Nav";`

Try changing it to:

`import { Nav } from "/path/to/Nav";`

---

Further explanation: exporting with `default` lets you omit curly braces when importing.

```
// if Nav component export looks like this:
export default Nav;
// OR
export { Nav as default };
// import it as such:
import Nav from "/path/to/Nav";

// if Nav component export looks like this:
module.exports = { Nav };
// import it as such:
import { Nav } from "/path/to/Nav";
```

The error `React.createElement: type should not be null[...]` can occur if you are using the wrong method of import (depends if module was exported with `default` or not).